# How to change a class to another class which derive from the same base class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a base class called Animal:

```
class Animal {

protected:    
    std::string name;
    int age;
    int weight;  
public:
    Animal(const std::string& _name, int _age, int _weight):name(_name),age(_age),weight(_weight) {};
    virtual void animal_cange(Animal*) = 0;
};
```

and from the Animal class derives two sublasses

```
class Dog : public Animal {

public:  
    Dog(const std::string& _name, int _age, int _weight) :Animal(_name, _age, _weight) {};
    void animal_cange(Animal* poot) override {

        this = new Cat(poot->name,poot->age,poot->weight);   
    }    
};
```

and this

```
class Cat : public Animal {

public:

    Cat(const std::string& _name, int _age, int _weight) :Animal(_name, _age, _weight) {};

    void animal_cange(Animal* poot) override {

        this = new Dog(name, age, weight);   
    }   
};
```

I made a virtual funcion in the base class caled `virtual void animal_cange(Animal*) = 0;` which should change a Dog object to a Cat object if it is called with the object's already existing name, age and weight value and visa versa but it always gives me error like:

> assignment to 'this' (anachronism)
>
> a value of type "Cat *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "Dog *"
>
> protected member "Animal::name" (declared at line 12) is not accessible through a pointer or object

I also tried without `animal_change` being a virtual function like this:

```
class Animal {

protected:    
    std::string name;
    int age;
    int weight;
public:
    Animal(const std::string& _name, int _age, int _weight):name(_name),age(_age),weight(_weight) {};
};



class Dog : public Animal {
public:    
    Dog(const std::string& _name, int _age, int _weight) :Animal(_name, _age, _weight) {};
    void animal_cange()  {

        this = new Cat(this->name,this->age,this->weight);
   }
};

class Cat : public Animal {

public:

    Cat(const std::string& _name, int _age, int _weight) :Animal(_name, _age, _weight) {};

    void animal_cange()  {

        *this = new Dog(name, age, weight);
    }
};
```

And the erorrs i get:

> `this = new Cat(this->name,this->age,this->weight);` : "assignment to 'this' (anachronism)" and the entity error
>
> "no operator matches these operands            operand types are: Cat = Dog *"

Comment: You cannot change class at runtime. What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen If the dog's weight is less than 40 than it turns into a cat, and if a cat's weight is more than 40 than it turns into a dog

Comment: you can convert a dog to a cat, but then it isnt a dog anymore, hence it is not the same object, at least in the C++ world (where converting dogs to cats is possible)

Comment: how do you want the calling code to look like? `animal_change` could return a new object of different type

Comment: You can also have a wrapper class, which stores `Animal*` and can change that pointer to other ones, or you can do that at place which stores `Animal*` directly.

Comment: @No_Name It sounds like you want a factory function to return a `Dog` or `Cat` object as an `Animal*` dependent on the weight value passed

Comment: @Lonesome Paradise How should i implement a factory function nicely?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen i haven't written wrapper class yet so i am not really sure how it should look like in my case. Can you show me?

Comment: @No_Name Thats a seperate question and has probably been asked here before or can be googled

Comment: [std::launder](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) has transmogrify example which might interest you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you cannot assign an object to one of a different class - that's what static type system is about. To "change" the dynamic type of a polymorphic object the client code can create another one like this:

```
Animal* animal = new Dog{}; // actually you should use smart pointers
if (want_to_change) {
  delete animal; // prevents a memory leak; smart pointers perform it automatically
  animal = new Cat{};
}
```

If you would like actual animal type choice to happen during initialization, consider using a factory:

```
class Factory {
public:
  // may be static if uses no state, than you can just write a free function
  Animal* produce(/* some parameters */) const;
};

Animal* Factory::produce(/* some parameters */) const {
  if (should_be_cat(/* depending on the parameters */)) {
    return new Cat{};
  } else {
    return new Dog{};
  }
}
```